# How do I center my text on an image using PIL in python and save the image with a different name in a for or while loop?

Tags: python, datetime, python-imaging-library

I'm trying to extract information from a word doc and write the paragraphs from there into images with borders and in the center of the image. In addition to this, I'm trying to save the image after each iteration, but with a different name, preferably like "patentDayMonthYearTime.png" that way it simply goes in chronological order.

```
import time
from PIL import Image
from PIL import ImageFont
from PIL import ImageDraw
from docx import Document

doc = Document('test.docx')
fullText = []

for para in doc.paragraphs:
    W, H = 300, 300
    body = Image.new('RGB', (W, H), (255, 255, 255))
    border = Image.new('RGB', (W+2, H+2), (0, 0, 0))
    border.save('border.png')
    body.save('body.png')
    patent = Image.open('border.png')
    patent.paste(body, (1, 1))
    draw = ImageDraw.Draw(patent)
    font = ImageFont.load_default()
    text = para.text.encode('utf-8')

    ch, pad = 60, 20
    for line in text:
        w, h = draw.textsize(line, font=font)
        draw.text(((W-w)/2, ch), line, (0, 0, 0), font=font)
        ch += h + pad

    date = time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d-%H:%M")
    patent.save('patent.png')
```

Above is my current code, and with it, I'm receiving the following error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/crazy/PycharmProjects/Patent/patent.py", line 28, in 
w, h = draw.textsize(line, font=font)

File "C:\Users\crazy\PycharmProjects\Patent\venv\lib\site-packages\PIL\ImageDraw.py", line 423, in textsize
if self._multiline_check(text):

File "C:\Users\crazy\PycharmProjects\Patent\venv\lib\site-packages\PIL\ImageDraw.py", line 258, in _multiline_check
return split_character in text
TypeError: argument of type 'int' is not iterable

Here is the document I'm currently working with:
[image]

Comment: Can you share sample docx file?

Comment: I added a snippet of the file... ignore the nonsense, it's just an example document, as the actual documents I need to be extracting from are both private and more complex.

Comment: This is just a hunch and may be completely off the mark, but:: It *looks* (assuming para.text is a string) like you are passing a byte array to draw.textsize(). Doesn't it take a string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're iterating over each letter, not each paragraph. I've fixed it and also added date into output filename. Here is the code:

```
import time
import textwrap
from docx import Document
from PIL import Image, ImageFont, ImageDraw

W, H = 300, 300

doc = Document('file.docx')
fullText = []

for i, p in enumerate(doc.paragraphs):

    body = Image.new('RGB', (W, H), (255, 255, 255))
    patent = Image.new('RGB', (W + 2, H + 2), (0, 0, 0))
    patent.paste(body, (1, 1))
    draw = ImageDraw.Draw(patent)
    font = ImageFont.load_default()

    current_h, pad = 60, 20
    for line in textwrap.wrap(p.text, width=40):
        w, h = draw.textsize(line, font=font)
        draw.text(((W - w) / 2, current_h), line, (0, 0, 0), font=font)
        current_h += h + pad

    patent.save(f'patent_{i+1}_{time.strftime("%Y%m%d%H%M%S")}.png')
```

Output files:

`patent_1_20201211092732.png`:

[image]

`patent_2_20201211092732.png`:

[image]

`patent_3_20201211092732.png`:

[image]

Comment: Thank you, this was a big help! Another thing though, I can't get my code to work without adding the encoding for latin-1, but when I add it, it gives me strange characters in place of quotations and such. Any ideas?